# Difference between solving T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/log n and T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n/log n using Master Method

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I recently stumbled upon a resource where the 2T(n/2) + n/log n **type** of recurrences were declared unsolvable by MM.

I accepted it as a lemma, until today, when another resource proved to be a contradiction (in some sense).

As per the resource (link below): Q7 and Q18 in it are the rec. 1 and 2 respectively in the question whereby, the answer to Q7 says it can't be solved by giving the reason 'Polynomial difference b/w f(n) and n^(log a base b)'.
On the contrary, answer 18 solves the second recurrence (in the question here) using case 1.

http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS433-CS9624/Resources/master.pdf

Can somebody please clear the confusion?

Comment: The case 18. is **4T(n/2)** not **4t(n/4)**. big difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to apply the master theorem to

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/log n
```

You consider `a = 2, b = 2`  which means `logb(a) = 1`

1. Can you apply case 1?`0 < c < logb(a) = 1`. Is `n/logn = O(n^c)`. No, because `n/logn` grow infinitely faster than `n^c`
2. Can you apply case 2? No. `c = 1` You need to find some ***k > 0*** such that `n/log n = Theta(n log^k n )`
3. Can you apply case 3 ? `c > 1`, is `n/logn = Big Omega(n^c)` ? No because it is not even `Big Omega(n)`

If you try to apply the master theorem to

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n/log n
```

You consider `a = 4, b = 2`  which means `logb(a) = 2`

1. Can you apply case 1? `c < logb(a) = 2`. is `n/logn = O(n^0)` or `n/logn = O(n^1)`. Yes indeed `n/logn = O(n)`. Thus we have

   ```
   T(n) = Theta(n^2)
   ```

***note: Explanation about 0 < c <1, case 1***

The case 1 is more about analytics.

```
f(x) = x/log(x) , g(x) = x^c , 0< c < 1
f(x) is O(g(x)) if f(x) < M g(x) after some x0, for some M finite, so 
f(x) is O(g(x)) if f(x)/g(x) < M cause we know they are positive
```

This isnt true here We pose `y = log x`

```
f2(y) = e^y/y , g2(y) = e^cy , 0< c < 1
f2(y)/g2(y) = (e^y/y) / (e^cy) = e^(1-c)y / y  , 0< c < 1

lim inf f2(y)/g2(y) = inf
lim inf f(x)/g(x) = inf
```

Comment: UmNyobe, may be i'm also unclear about the case 1 then.
Here's my understanding. 
Case 1 says that f(n) 'part' of the recurrence must be O(n^(log a base b - e)) where e is a constant > 0

So what's wrong with n/log n = O(n^(1-some c : 0<c<1)) ? 
So, may be not case 3 but can apply case 1 to both..

Comment: No `x/logx` grows [infinitely faster](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim++%28x%2Flogx%29%2F%28x%5E0.99999999%29) than  `x^c` , 0< c <1

Comment: Mine goodness.. I thought the fraction has x divided by a function of x, viz. log x so it has got to be less than x..

So, what about your point # 3? It's not even big-omega (n^c).

Comment: same as case 1. please do the math.

Comment: Nope! I didn't get why you say that n/log n grows 'infinitely' faster than n^c.. 
and then it is not even >= c. n^c.. (big-omega).

I understand the explanation of 4T(n/2), n/log n being O(n^2) to fall in case 1 for "exponent strictly bigger than the exponent of the polynomial part of n/log(n)" from Simone's answer..

Comment: I guess I get it now.. n/log n is not big-omega(n^c) because that case says f(n) should be big-omega(n^(log a base b + e)) : e > 0.
It is because of this e.. right?

Comment: UmNyobe, can you please confirm that hence, all rec. of the form 
T(n) = a T(n/a) + n/log n are not solvable by MM.. ?

Comment: looking the way you stated seems more complicated than anything else. I used a proof by contradiction. n^c, c> 1 is big omega n. if f(n) is big omega n^c, then f is big omega n (big O and omega are transitive). Showing that n/log n is not even big omega of function `n` means it is not going to be big omega n^c, c > 1. You can also take one value of c (like 2) and show that it doesn work. And yes `T(n) = a T(n/a) + n/log n` are not solvable by MM is the conclusion you can have.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in Q18 we have `a = 4` and `b = 2`, thus we get that `n^{log(b,a)} = n^2` which has an exponent strictly bigger than the exponent of the polynomial part of `n/log(n)`.

Comment: Simone, so what is the story between 'strictly' (n^2) and 'seemingly' (n) bigger in contrast to 2T(n/2) (the first rec.)?

f(n) = n/log n is O(n) and O(n^2)..